# What does <function at ...> mean

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Here's the code:

```
def my_func(f, arg):
  return f(arg)

print((lambda x: 2*x*x, (5)))

>>>(<function <lambda> at 0x10207b9d8>, 5)
```

How to solve the error, and can some please explain in a clear language what exactly that error means.

Comment: What were you *trying* to do? Did you want to apply the lambda function to 5?

Comment: What error is it that you're receiving?

Comment: You're not calling 'my_func' in the print statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error; you simply supplied two arguments to `print`, the `lambda x: 2*x*x` and `5`. You're not calling your anonymous function rather, just passing it to `print`.

`print` will then call the objects `__str__` method which returns what you see:

```
>>> str(lambda x: 2*x*x)  # similarly for '5'
'<function <lambda> at 0x7fd4ec5f0048>'
```

Instead, fix your parenthesis to actually *call* the lambda with the `5` passed as the value for `x`:

```
print((lambda x: 2*x*x)(5))
```

which prints out `50`.

---

> What's the general meaning of `<function at 0x ...>`?

That's simply the way Python has chosen to represent function objects when printed. Their `str` takes the name of the function and the `hex` of the `id` of the function and prints it out. E.g:

```
def foo(): pass
print(foo) # <function foo at 0x7fd4ec5dfe18>
```

Is created by returning the string:

```
"<function {0} at {1}>".format(foo.__name__, hex(id(foo)))
```

Comment: Ok thank you. But I had many other functions that gave me the message. I just wanted to know and understand what's the general meaning of <function at 0x ...> ???